# Map Guid Property to Oracle in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to map a Guid property to Oracle. Here's its declaration:

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0, TypeName = "RAW")]
[MaxLength(16)]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

However, I keep getting the following exception:

Schema specified is not valid. Errors:

```
(7,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Guid[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 'Id' in type 'Model.Test' is not compatible with 'OracleEFProvider.raw[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=2000,FixedLength=False]' of member 'Id' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Test'.
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

RP

Comment: I believe the MaxLength attribute is a no-op in this case. If you look at the type definition you will see that MaxLength is 2000 and not 16. btw. Have you tried not using the `Column` attribute at all (or just not specifying the type). The provider should know how to map the GUID type to a database type. btw. What Oracle provider do you use?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am using the latest ODAC. Even without the Column and MaxLength attributes, it doesn't work. I managed to get around it by switching from Guid to Byte[], but I believe this can be achieved.

Comment: You might be able to use Raw(17) instead of 16. This maps to type binary. But then you have to figure out how handle the bytes

Answer (score 4):

I have given up, since I got no response from either Oracle or Microsoft. As far as I can tell, there is no way to have Entity Framework Code First use Guids on Oracle.
I am using a String instead of the Guid, but I still populate it with a Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), so that I have a unique primary key.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. That's so frustrating there does not seem to be any solution to this... Thanks for nothing Oracle/Microsoft....

Comment: Can I use EF Code First using ODP.NET ? ODAC 12c not supports EF Code First.

Comment: I am way too deep into the project to change PK type. Should I add another ID column type string?

Comment: What do you mean, @Toolkit? Having a composite primary key? In fact, this question is too old, now I'm using EF Core, so I don't think this still applies.

Comment: No not a composite key. Additional numeric key. So I can do things like `db.MyTable.Find(id);` Because with Raw-Guid it is impossible

Comment: But Find only works with the primary key. I guess you could change the current Guid/RAW one to be just unique and then add another primary key of other type?

Comment: OK `Find` probably not a necessity, can be `First`. So the option I am considering is to introduce something like `ID1` type string and change all searches to use it. For example when an AJAX call comes I will be using that ID1 rather than ID. Seems like the least pain to me rather than changing PK type now

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that there is no direct mapping of the Oracle Data Type of "RAW(16)" to the EDM type of "Guid". You can find this information in the Developer Guide at:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/entityEDMmapping.htm#ODPNT8275

We had run into the same exact issue, but was able to solve it by simply removing the configuration of the "TypeName" property on the [Column] attribute. Below is a sample of how we decorated our code-first Entity property.

```
[Column("ColumnName")]
public Guid Uid{ get; set; }
```

I don't know why this work, but it just does. Hopefully Oracle updates their EF library to be able to use something like TypeName = "RAW(16)". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did a reverse engineering to see how Oracle handles the RAW primary key and here's what I have found:

**Existing Database Setup:**

Column Name: MSID

Type: RAW

Length: 20

Default: SYS_GUID()

**Generated Model (scaffold-dbcontext):**

```
[Column("MSID")]
[MaxLength(20)]
public byte[] Msid { get; set; }
```

**Generated Context:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MsmSample>(entity =>
{
  entity.HasKey(e => e.Msid)
        .HasName("MSM_SAMPLE_PK");

  entity.HasIndex(e => e.Msid)
        .HasName("MSM_SAMPLE_PK")
        .IsUnique();

  entity.Property(e => e.Msid).HasDefaultValueSql("sys_guid()");
});
```