# How to Query with Guid on Oracle

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework

I'm developing an ASP.NET application with Entity Framework 5.0 and Oracle 11g Database. I also use Oracle Membership and I have `ORA_ASPNET_USERS` table where i store users' information.

My problem is that when i try to query a user by Guid (for example : "{d19b8b68-cc4f-5449-9ba6-ac2573f34bcc}") no result is found because in Oracle Database this Guid is stored as "688B9BD14FCC49549BA6AC2573F34BCC".

I can convert Guid to Oracle RAW using the code below:

```
var id = BitConverter.ToString(guid.ToByteArray()).Replace("-", "");
```

But when i try to query a user using EF, i have to do it like this in my business object:

```
var result = GetQueryable().Where(w => w.USERID == id).Single();
```

and `USERID` is a type of `Guid` and i can not query it with id (type of `string`).

When i do not convert guid to byte array, no result is found.

Does anyone have the same problem? How can i solve it?

Comment: check this out 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813349/map-guid-property-to-oracle-in-entity-framework-code-first

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But there is no solution on the link. I still have the problem. I have to query a user by .NET Guid on ORACLE Raw but i can't do it.

Comment: Well, the link is show you that people asked this question before, and answer yet for it. check this from Oracle forum https://community.oracle.com/thread/2319113?tstart=0

Comment: In this link it is said that the bug has been fixed in ODAC 12c R3. I downloaded and installed it but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: I still have the same problem and couldn't find any solution. Can anyone help me about my problem?